# Creating a form in WordPress in a class-based plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a custom plugin that uses a class.  In the class I add an admin dashboard menu item that displays a "Settings" form.  Let's say the class looks like this:

```
class MyPlugin {

  function __construct () { ... }

  function show_menu_form () {
    $url = admin_url("admin_post
    echo <<<EOFORM
      <form method="POST" action="$url"/>
        Click submit to do stuff.
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_stuff"/>
        <input type="submit/>
      </form>
EOFORM;        
    add_action('wp_post_do_stuff', [$this, '_handle_stuff']);
  }

  function _handle_stuff () {
    echo "Doing stuff...";
  }
}
```

The form prints properly in the dashboard page.  When I click submit, it goes to a completely blank screen.  What I want it to do is:

- Do something
- Go back to the same page, showing a message like, "Stuff was done." above the same form, and the user can click the form submit again to do more stuff.

If I leave the action blank on the <form> tag it will go back to the same page, and I can manually process the get/post params myself... that seems like a bad solution (but the only one I can see so far).

Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do this:

1. **Form submit to the same page** and before rendering the form you check if the form already submitted. If yes then call a function to display "Stuff was done" and any further steps. If not, then display the form.
   In this way, you won't need any javascript in your plugin and I IMOO will be simpler and straight forward.
2. **Submit using AJAX** and display the confirm message using javascript. You can read the docs [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) to see how to do this in the admin menu. This is might be a more elegant solution without requiring any page refresh.

Which one to use depends on the requirements of your plugin. Either way, don't forget to validate inputs